# Eclipse not finding definitions from included headers in included header

Tags: c, eclipse, include

I'm resuming a project in eclipse for C/C++ projects.
The project already exists and compiles.
Eclipse can't find symbols in included files referenced in included files.
E.g.

**/path/to/headers/included_included.h**

```
#define ABC "A"
```

**/path/to/headers/included.h**

```
#include <included_included.h>
```

**/path/to/code.c**

```
...
does_things(ABC)
...
```

In this case, gcc can find the symbol ABC but eclipse can't.
However, if I include the other file like this, `#include <included_included.h>`, eclipse can find the symbol without issues.

There are no conditionals which could prevent the include of `included_included.h` from happening in the `included.h` file

I'm using eclipse `4.13`

I want eclipse to be able to reach the second included file.

Comment: Have you tried exiting Eclipse and starting it again?

Comment: Yep! PC restart too

Comment: Have you tried recompiling all?

Comment: I haven't and, for some reason.... Recompiling all manually (that's the important part) and then restarting eclipse solved it.... I have no understanding why.... There's no build configurations set